# Imagick is very slow when writing an image modified with ImageDraw in GIF format

Tags: php, performance, imagick

Here is an example of the code where I'm trying to draw 10 pictures with a simple line on them:

```
$pixel = new ImagickPixel( 'white' );
foreach (range(0, 9) as $x) {
    $image = new Imagick();
    $image->setFormat('gif');
    $image->newImage(320, 60, $pixel);

    $line = new ImagickDraw();
    $line->line(0, 0, 100, 100);
    $image->drawImage($line);

    $image->writeImage(__DIR__ . '/images/' . $x . '.gif');
}
```

For some reason this code takes ~0.5 sec to execute which is way too much for a highload application. I tried to do the same thing with PHP GD library and Python's PIL: both showed me pretty decent results around 0.01 sec for the same operation.

So, is **Imagick that slow** in general? Or is there some trick to optimize the `writeImage` method (which takes the most time to execute)?

PHP 7.4, Ubuntu 20.04, ImageMagick 6.9.10-23.
Also tested it on different machines (incl. docker) and environments with different php versions.

P.S. I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11606654/slow-font-rendering-in-imagemagick) topic, but it was asked 8 years ago, so I can't be sure it's still relevant. Looks like php-gmamgick library is abandoned.

**UPD:** after some research I can confirm that problem happens only when trying to write a GIF format. Since my eventual goal is to generate an animated gif, it sounds bad for me.

Here is an example of the code which is generating a simple animation. In this case, each frame is generated pretty fast (even if I save all frames as separate jpg images). But when I'm writing a GIF result, it takes half a second.

```
<?php

$time = microtime(true);
$pixel = new ImagickPixel( 'white' );
$gif = new Imagick();
$gif->setFormat("jpg");

foreach (range(0, 9) as $x) {
    $image = new Imagick();
    $image->setFormat('jpg');
    $image->newImage(320, 60, $pixel);

    $draw = new ImagickDraw();
    $draw->setFillColor('Black');
    $draw->setFontSize(10);
    $image->annotateImage($draw, 10, 10, 0, $x);

    // I don't need to save each frame, just testing that it works fast for jpg format
    $image->writeImage(__DIR__ . '/images/' .  $x . '.jpg');

    $image->setImageDelay(100);
    $gif->addImage($image);
}

$gif->deconstructImages();

echo 'Generating frames: ' .  (microtime(true) - $time) . PHP_EOL;

$time = microtime(true);

$gif->writeImages(__DIR__ . '/result/imagick_animated.gif', true);

echo 'Writing GIF: ' . (microtime(true) - $time) . PHP_EOL;
```

Output:

```
Generating frames: 0.050290822982788
Writing GIF: 0.43121600151062
```

So now I suppose it's ImageMagick downside which operates GIFs slowly (Python's PIL works 10x faster for the same animation). I just need to confirm this or understand how to optimize it.

Comment: If something is slow, you need to benchmark it properly to see where your time is going. Have you tried commenting out the line drawing and running a few thousand iterations? Then commenting out the file saving and timing a few thousand iterations? Then writing a JPEG or PPM file instead of a GIF to see if that is the cause? Have you tried `libvips`?

Comment: How are you measuring this? Does it take 0.5s for the whole script or only part of it?  I executed this and get under 0.1 even with lower PHP-Version. tested only for the loop part.

Comment: Are you running on a Raspberry Pi Zero? Or with a FAT-32 format filesystem on a 5,400 rpm disk?

Comment: as stated by @MarkSetchell the image format may have a huge impact on your execution time, ImageMagic is trying to perform some improvements while creating images. (jpg = 0.02s, gif=0.1, png=0.09). Therefore an comparison of execution time between  imagemagick and gdlib does not make sense as both are working differently and for different purposes. If you really want to draw only simple  images with an line within, then use gdlib... no need to use ImageMagick.

Comment: @ChristianFelix I need to render images with complex text content, I'm just running performance testing with simple lines so far. GD library may be not enough for my goal.

Comment: @Mark Setchell it works fast if I change format to JPG, you are right. But my eventual goal is to generate an animated gif from that 10 frames. And when I use `Imagick::writeImages('result.gif', true)`, this command takes 0.5 sec to execute. So here I can clarify that problem occurs only when writing GIF format. Any idea how can I improve that?

Comment: @MarkSetchell as for your previous questions. It takes long only when both commands writeImage AND imageDraw are used. If I write an untouched image or if I draw an image without saving it works fine. I'm testing on a modern desktop machine with fast SSD and itntel i7. I didn't try libvips though, which I will test soon, thanks.

Comment: let me say it in another way: which vehicle is faster for the first 10 meters: a) an aeroplan b) an e-bike ? hm, the answer should be simple.  The test you are running does not take considerable amount of items to say it fast or slow, as you generating only 10 images with no content in it. ImageMagic offers up to 400 methods for manipulating images, so the time it takes will take considerable more time than gdlib. Show us the complex case, maybe it will get us further.

Comment: I updated my answer and attached an example of the code which generates an animated gif (a little bit more real example for my case)

Comment: imagemagick will try to generate an optimized GIF, and this is very expensive. It will search for differences between frames, try to minimize the changes it stores in the file, and select an optimal palette. You'll probably find that the GIF generated by GD or PIL is larger. IM have a page introducing animation optimization: http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/anim_opt/